# Name for a shape consisting of the union of all spheres of a given radius centered at all points in a triangular (or tetrahedral) region?

Tags: geometry, terminology, 3d, sumset

I'm struggling with finding a name for the following object:

Suppose we have a set of points. For example a triangle, including the area inside the triangle, its edges and its vertices. We then construct a sphere at each point of that triangle with the same radius for all the spheres. We then take the union of all these spheres. What would be a name for the resulting object? What would be the name for its surface?

Also, what would be the name of such a shape obtained through the same process but with a tetrahedron instead of a triangle?

Comment: This object goes by many names. It can be expressed as a *Minkowski sum* of the triangle with the ball of the specified radius, but is also known as a *generalized ball,* *$\epsilon$-neighborhood of a set*, or an *$\epsilon$-thickening*.

Comment: @William you could post that as an answer so this no longer remains unanswered

Comment: Please, learn concepts, not names! It's mathematics, not magic.

Comment: One could also call this set, using more classical geometry language, the _locus of points a distance at most $r$ from your shape (triangle, tetrahedron etc.)_, where $r$ is the fixed radius of the spheres

Comment: @wasn'tme Agreed, but in this case I really need a name. I'm using it inside computer code I'm writing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this is a notion that is given many names in the literature. Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, and $B_r(x)$ denote the $d$-dimensional ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. Then it is a cute exercise of metric set theory to prove that:

$$S + B_r(0) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \exists s \in S \text{ such that } d(s,x)\leq r\} = \bigcup_{s \in S} B_r(s)$$
Where $A + B = \{a + b : a \in A, b \in B\}$ is the Minkowksi (or set) sum of $A$ and $B$. The first set in the above chain of equalities is known either just as a Minkowski sum, or as a *generalized ball* (can you see which choice of $S$ recovers the standard ball?); the second set is known as an $r$-*neighborhood, fattening, or thickening* of $S$. Obviously, the third set is the one you described.